# Flutter Transceive ISO 15693 iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, iso-15693

I'm trying to read multiple blocks using transcieve flutter_nfc_kit and its working using android but failed using iOS.

```
Uint8List command = Uint8List(12);
command[0] = 0x60;
command[1] = 0x23;
command[2...9] = UID; 
command[10] = 0x00; 
command[11] = 0x04; 
Uint8List result = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(command);
```

Response I got from debugging iOS

```
[NFCTagReaderSession transceive:tagUpdate:error:]:888 Error Domain=NFCError Code=102 "Stack Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stack Error, NSUnderlyingError=0x2812d88a0 {Error Domain=nfcd Code=10 "Invalid Parameter" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Parameter}}}
```